# Angular 4 *ngIf in template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

in template I have a table where I want if entry .status === "applied with errors" then it should return a link (with anchor tag> otherwise just a conext.  I m trying with below code but its giving me error- Template parse error.

Any help.

```
 <ng-container   *ngFor="let entry of Entries;let idx=index"> 
     <td *ngIf="{{entry.status == Applied with Errors}} ? 
'<a>{{ entry.status }}</a>' : '{{ entry.status }}'">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is vague, Based on my understanding I suggest you Show an alternative template using `else`

```
<ng-container   *ngFor="let entry of Entries;let idx=index"> 
            <td *ngIf="entry.status ==='Applied with Errors'; else elseblock"> 
       <a>{{ entry.status }}</a></td>

       <ng-template #elseblock>
            <td> {{entry.status}} </td>
    </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
```